# How to add a text delimiter correctly in Python

Tags: python, django, csv, export

I want to export some data from DB to CSV file. I need to add a '|' delimiter to specific fields. At the moment when I export file, I use something like that:
- To specific fields (at the end and beginning) I add '|':

```
....
if response.value_display.startswith('|'):
                        sheets[response.sheet.session][response.input.id] = response.value_display
                    else:
                        sheets[response.sheet.session][response.input.id] = '|'+response.value_display+'|'
....
```

- And I have CSV writer function settings like that:

```
self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect,
                                 lineterminator='\n',
                                 quotechar='',
                                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
                                 escapechar=' ',
                                 ** kwargs)
```

Now It works, but when I have DateTime fields(where is space) writer adds some extra space.

When I have default settings (sometimes) at the end and beginning CSV writer add double-quotes but I don't know why and what it depends on.

Answer (score 1):

To remove your extra spaces I would just do something like.

```py
    file = open(the_file.csv, w+) #open your csv file
    file.write(file.readline().replace("  ", " ") #finds any two spaces and replaces with one
    file.close()
```

With the delimiter it is specific to the situation. If you want to add it at the beginning or the end.

```py
    delimiter = "|"
    my_str = my_str + delimiter
```

or

```py
    delimiter = "|"
    my_str = delimiter + my_str
```

If you want to add the delimiter somewhere else you may have to get creative as it would be based on the context.

I'm not sure on the double quotes. I'd replace like the spaces.

```py
    file = open(the_file.csv, w+) #open your csv file
    file.write(file.readline().replace("\"", "'") 
    file.close()
```

Assuming you wanted to replace the double quote with a single quote.